# Student ids in a list not getting printed out

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to print out an unsorted, then sorted list of student IDs after the user enters them in. It prints an empty list fine, but when there are actual ids to print, it just goes blank. Why is this happening? I can only get an empty list to work right but not a list with anything in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf, scanf                                  */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, exit, free                             */
#include <ctype.h>  /* typedef, tolower                               */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                          Symbolic Constants                        */
/**********************************************************************/

#define MAXIMUM_ID        999999  /* Maximum student id number        */
#define MINIMUM_ID        1       /* Minimum student id number        */
#define LIST_HEADER       MINIMUM_ID - 1
                                  /* Header of the student id list    */
#define LIST_TRAILER      MAXIMUM_ID + 1 
                                  /* Trailer of the student id list   */
#define HEADER_ALLOC_ERR  1       /* Error allocating the list header */
                                  /* memory                           */
#define TRAILER_ALLOC_ERR 2       /* Error allocating the list        */
                                  /* trailer memory                   */
#define ID_ALLOC_ERR      3       /* Error allocating the student id  */
                                  /* memory                           */
#define QUIT              0       /* Program exit value               */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                          Program Structures                        */
/**********************************************************************/
/* A school student id list                                           */
struct student_id
{
   int               student_id;      /* A student's id number        */
   struct student_id *p_next_student; /* Points to next student id    */
};
typedef struct student_id ID;

/**********************************************************************/
/*                          Function Prototypes                       */
/**********************************************************************/
void print_heading();
   /* Print the program heading                                       */
void print_instructions();
   /* Print the program instructions                                  */
char get_response();
   /* Get the response to continue or quit                            */
ID *create_empty_list();
   /* Create an empty list                                            */
void insert_student(ID *p_id_list, int student_id);
   /* Insert a student at the front of the list                       */
void print_list(ID *p_id_list);
   /* Print all the student id's in the list                          */
int get_count(ID *p_id_list);
   /* Get the count of the students on the list                       */
void sort_list(ID *p_student_id);
   /* Sort the students into ascending order by id                    */
void remove_duplicates(ID *p_id_list);
   /* Remove all duplicate id's                                       */

/**********************************************************************/
/*                             Main Function                          */
/**********************************************************************/
int main()
{
   ID  *p_id_list,   /* Points to the student id list                 */
       *p_next_list; /* Points to each student id in the list         */
   int  student_id;  /* A student's id number                         */

   /* Loop processing student id list until the user says to quit     */
   while(print_instructions(), get_response() == 'y')
   {
      /* Create an empty list of student IDs                          */
      p_id_list = create_empty_list();

      /* Loop processing inserted student ids until the user says     */
      /* to quit                                                      */
      while(printf("Enter the next student id (%d to quit): ", QUIT),
            scanf ("%d", &student_id), student_id > LIST_HEADER)
      {
         if(student_id > MAXIMUM_ID)
         {
            printf("    Id rejected - it cannot exceed %d", MAXIMUM_ID);
            printf("\n");
         }
         else
            insert_student(p_id_list, student_id);
      }

      /* Print the list of unsorted student ID's and show the number  */
      /* of student IDs                                               */
      printf("\nThe unsorted student ID list, as entered, is: ");
      print_list(p_id_list);
      printf("\nThe length of the unsorted student ID list is: %d", 
         get_count(p_id_list));

      /* Print the list of sorted student ID's and show the number of */
      /* student IDs                                                  */
      sort_list(p_id_list);
      printf("\n\nThe student id list, sorted ascending by id, is:");
      print_list(p_id_list);
      printf("\nThe length of the sorted student ID list is: %d", 
         get_count(p_id_list));

      /* Delete duplicate student IDs, print the student id list,     */
      /* show the number of student ids, and free the id list         */
      printf("\n");
      remove_duplicates(p_id_list);
      printf("\nThe student id list, with duplicate id's removed,");
      printf("sorted ascending by id, is:");
      print_list(p_id_list); 
      printf("\nThe length of the cleared and sorted student"); 
      printf("ID list is: %d", get_count(p_id_list));

      while(p_id_list != NULL)
      {
         p_next_list = p_id_list->p_next_student;
         free(p_id_list);
         p_id_list = p_next_list;
      }
   }

   /* Print a goodbye message and terminate the program               */
   printf("\n\nThanks for using this program. Have a great day! :D");
   printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
   return 0;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                   Print the program instructions                   */
/**********************************************************************/
void print_instructions()
{
   printf("\n\n\n  This program maintains a list of elements by their");
   printf(    "\n  id number.  After entry of all id's, it sorts them");
   printf(    "\n  into ascending order, then removes all duplicates.");
   return;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                Get the response to continue or quit                */
/**********************************************************************/
char get_response()
{
   char response[2]; /* Response to continue or quit                  */

   printf("\n");
   do
   {
      printf("\nDo you want to enter another student id list (y or n): ");
      scanf ("%1s", &response[0]);
      response[0] = tolower(response[0]);
   }
   while(response[0] != 'y' && response[0] != 'n');

   return (response[0]);
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                        Create an empty list                        */
/**********************************************************************/
ID *create_empty_list()
{
   ID *p_new_list; /* List of student ID's                            */

   if((p_new_list = (ID *)malloc(sizeof(ID))) == NULL)
   {
      printf("\n\nError #%d occurred in create_empty_list",
                                                      HEADER_ALLOC_ERR);
       printf(  "\nUnable to allocate memory for the list header.");
       printf(  "\nThe program is aborting.");
       exit  (HEADER_ALLOC_ERR);
   }
   p_new_list->student_id = LIST_HEADER;

   if((p_new_list->p_next_student = (ID *)malloc(sizeof(ID))) == NULL)
   {
      printf("\n\nError #%d occurred in create_empty_list",
                                                     TRAILER_ALLOC_ERR);
      printf(  "\nUnable to allocate memory for the list header.");
       printf(  "\nThe program is aborting.");
       exit  (TRAILER_ALLOC_ERR);
   }
   p_new_list->p_next_student->student_id = LIST_TRAILER;
   p_new_list->p_next_student->p_next_student = NULL;

   return p_new_list;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*             Insert a student at the front of the list              */
/**********************************************************************/
void insert_student(ID *p_id_list, int insert_id)
{
   ID *p_current_id = p_id_list->p_next_student,
      *p_new_list,  /* Points to the new id list                      */
      *p_previous_id = p_id_list;

   while(

   if((p_new_list = (ID *)malloc(sizeof(ID))) == NULL)
   {
      printf("\n\nError #%d occurred in insert_student", ID_ALLOC_ERR);
       printf(  "\nUnable to allocate memory for a new student id.");
       printf(  "\nThe program is aborting.");
       exit  (ID_ALLOC_ERR);
   }

   p_new_list->student_id     = insert_id;
   p_new_list->p_next_student = p_current_id;
   p_previous_id->p_next_student  = p_new_list;

   return;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*               Print all the student id's in the list               */
/**********************************************************************/
void print_list(ID *p_id_list)
{
   printf("\nEntering print_list");
   if(get_count(p_id_list) == LIST_HEADER)
      printf("\n   The student id list is empty.");
   else
   {
      while(p_id_list = p_id_list->p_next_student,
            p_id_list->student_id < LIST_TRAILER)
      {
         printf("\nEntering loop");
         printf("\n                   %6d", p_id_list->student_id);
      }
   }

   return;
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*              Get the count of the students on the list             */
/**********************************************************************/
int get_count(ID *p_id_list)
{
   int student_count=0; /* Counts the length of the id list           */

   while(p_id_list->p_next_student->student_id != LIST_TRAILER)
      student_count += 1;

   return(student_count);
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*            Sort the students into ascending order by id            */
/**********************************************************************/
void sort_list(ID *p_student_id)
{
   ID  *p_id_list,     /* Pointer to a student ID                     */
       *p_temp_id;     /* Pointer to a temporary student ID           */
   int student_number; /* Student ID sorting counter                  */

   for (student_number = 0; student_number < get_count(p_student_id);
                                                       student_number++)
   {
      p_id_list = p_student_id;

      while(p_id_list->p_next_student->p_next_student->student_id !=
            LIST_TRAILER)
      {
         if(p_id_list->p_next_student->student_id < 
            p_id_list->p_next_student->p_next_student->student_id)
         {
            p_temp_id                 = 
               p_id_list->p_next_student->p_next_student;
            p_id_list->p_next_student->p_next_student
               = p_temp_id->p_next_student;
            p_temp_id->p_next_student = p_id_list->p_next_student;
            p_id_list->p_next_student    = p_temp_id;
         }
         p_student_id = p_student_id->p_next_student;
      }
   }
}

/**********************************************************************/
/*                      Remove all duplicate id's                     */
/**********************************************************************/
void remove_duplicates(ID *p_id_list)
{
   ID *p_current_id  = p_id_list->p_next_student,  
                                  /* Points to the current id         */
      *p_previous_id = p_id_list; /* Points to the previous id        */

   printf("\n");
   while(p_current_id->student_id != LIST_TRAILER)
   {
      if(p_previous_id->student_id == p_current_id->student_id)
      {
         printf("\nDeleting the duplicate student id: %d",
                                              p_current_id->student_id);
         p_previous_id->p_next_student = p_current_id->p_next_student;
         free(p_current_id);
         p_current_id = p_previous_id->p_next_student;
      }
      else
      {
         p_previous_id = p_previous_id->p_next_student;
         p_current_id  = p_current_id->p_next_student;
      }
   }

   return;
}
```

I'm not sure which function is the problem because it al sems alright to me.

Comment: "because it al sems alright to me". How did you come to that conclusion? Just reviewing the code is often not enough. Run your program in a debugger and step through the code to see what it is doing.

Comment: If you follow my advice you will quickly find the problem (it took me 1 minute with the debugger). Hint: Look in `get_count`.

Comment: @kaylum I did run it through a debugger but it acted like it couldn’t tell there was a problem.

Comment: The debugger doesn't tell you where the problem is. It only allows you to examine what the program is doing. You need to interpret the results. In this case, if you put a break point in `print_list` then step through the code you will find it never exits `get_count`. Heck even adding more debug print statements would be able to reach that conclusion. I'm just trying to encourage you to develop good debugging techniques.

Comment: @kaylum I see what you mean. But if the problem is in the get_count, how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't know how to fix it. You are correctly traversing the list in all the other parts of the code. I just assumed you made a typo and would know how to fix it when pointed out to you: `while(p_id_list->p_next_student->student_id != LIST_TRAILER)` . That is not traversing the list at all. It is just checking the same record over and over again.

Comment: I've added an answer to make it clearer for you. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `get_count` there is an infinete loop because it is checking the same `p_id_list` over and over again without ever moving to the next record.

```
while(p_id_list->p_next_student->student_id != LIST_TRAILER)
    student_count += 1;
```

Just need to ensure that the next record is visited on each loop. For example:

```
ID *cur = p_id_list->p_next_student;
while (cur->student_id != LIST_TRAILER) {
    student_count += 1;
    cur = cur->p_next_student;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it gave me a segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, you have a bug else where. I think I'll leave it to you to debug from here as that's a different problem. Please continue to learn to use the debugger more effectively. With that you should see that now `get_count` is working fine, the unsorted `print_list` works fine but the next thing blows up. Please try to debug it yourself now and post a new question if you get stuck again. But please do try first.